# How to randomize integers without rand()?

Tags: c++, random

I have to code a random roll of dice but I can only use the headers `<iomanip>` and `<iostream>`, which is why `rand()` is not possible. I've tried a few things but all of them return errors, is there a way to have a random roll of dice without the usage of `rand()`?

Comment: Use a random engine not a rand().

Comment: You can create a variable, then get the address of it and mod 6

Comment: Try reading the wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generation#Computational_methods. There are some basic formulas for simple pseudo-random number generation

Comment: If this is your homework, please provide the exact wording of the assignment. Also, please tell us what you have tried so far.  Also, please have a look at [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Comment: My favorite is [Xorshift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xorshift).

Comment: You did not define your requirements for the randomness. What distribution? What randomness quality? Without that, `int myrand() { return 42; }` is a good answer.

Comment: "I've tried a few things but all of them return errors".  Please show them.

Answer (score 4):

You can code your own pseudo-random generator, there are some simple ones like [Park-Miller RNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehmer_random_number_generator) which is just:

```cpp
uint32_t lcg_parkmiller(uint32_t *state)
{
    return *state = (uint64_t)*state * 48271 % 0x7fffffff;
}
```

You can then create a `uint32_t state` variable and repeatedly call the function to advance the random state. To get the dice roll, just compute `state % 6`.

That being said, you still need an initial value (seed) for the random number generator. Usually time (with nanosecond precision) or some other rapidly changing factor is used, so what you can use depends on what includes you are allowed to use.

Comment: The only problem I see with this is that `uint32_t` and `uint64_t` are defined in `cstdint`.

Comment: Curiously, why `% 0x7fffffff` to lop off to 31 bits and not just `return *state = (uint34_t)((uint64_t)*state * 48271);` and use 32 bits?

Comment: @TedLyngmo They could be changed to unsigned integer types.

Comment: @Ranoiaetep Yes, that would certainly make it work without having to include `cstdint`. Perhaps a few _constexpr-ifs_ would be needed to make sure that the proper unsigned types are used in the function though.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Seems like `char16_t` and `char32_t` are fixed size and are fundamental types, and you can apply similar math to them

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica The multiplier, additive constant (when used), and modulus of an LCG have to all satisfy a set of mutually dependent constraints to achieve full cycle.  (See the Wikipedia article for details.)  You can't just change the modulus without revisiting the other coefficients. Note that LCGs go way back to the days where you couldn't make assumptions about the sizes of registers or behavior when sign bits were involved.  I suspect this is an old variant that uses 31 bits to avoid stepping on those sorts of land mines.

Comment: @pjs True that the multiplier, offset and modulus are a package deal.  Apparently there is no 32 bits period set with an increment of 0.  Code could have been `*state = (uint64_t)*state * 22695477 + 1;` and achieved 2^32 cycle rather than `(uint64_t)*state * 48271 % 0x7fffffff;` which gets stuck on landmine `*state== 0`

Answer (score 0):

You can use an algorithm like the [Linear Congruential Generator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator), which can be implemented without using any C++ libraries. Here is an
example implementation. Note that some values `modulus` results in missing values in the dice sequence (1-6), so it should be chosen carefully. A large prime number tends to work. The multiplier `a` and increment `b` match the values used in glibc.

```
int main()
{
    
    long val = 3;
    long a = 1103515245;
    long b = 12345;
    long modulus = 7883;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        val = ((a * val) + b) % modulus;
        
        cout << ((val < 0 ? -val : val)%6)+1 << ",";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Looks like signed integer overflow is going to hit this one and cause undefined behavior.

Comment: Good catch @Ted. Yes, the value does wrap, which is why the Absolute value is taken when outputing the result. But if you are concerned that wrapping is undefined, then your options are to use a `long long` integer type for the values, or reduce the size of `a`. There will be plenty of smaller values of `a` that will work. I just chose that particular size to mimic the ones used in `glibc`.

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to just use `unsigned long`s?

Comment: @Ted, that would work too. It would be like using another mod!

Comment: Yes, but without UB. :)

Answer (score -2):

> *I have to code a random roll of dice but I can only use the headers `<iomanip>` and `<iostream>`, which is why `rand()` is not possible.*

If you are using `<iomanip>` and `<iostream>` chances are you can use `rand()`.

As you can see in this [**live sample**](https://godbolt.org/z/b3TvcKbjj) it works with 2 different compilers.

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

int main() {

  srand(time(NULL));

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    int x = rand() % 50 + 1;
    std::cout << x << " ";
  }
}
```

Note that, `srand`, `rand` and `time` are not mandated to be part of any of these two headers so you should document it, though the best approach would be, of course, to include the required header.

---

Comment: I believe whoever gave the OP the task said they shouldn't use `rand()` *as well as* not use any other headers except <iostream> and <iomanip>

Comment: @StackDanny, that may very well be the case, but the statement is *"I can only use the headers <iomanip> and <iostream>, which is why rand() is not possible"*, which leads me to believe the OP believes that it's not possible to use `rand` with those 2 headers, which is not the case.

Comment: “It might work” is not a good approach to programming. Neither of those headers is required to define `rand()`, `srand()`, or `time()`.

Comment: A simple update of the compiler could break the code if you are relying on random chance like this.

Comment: @Galik, I aprreciate the rigor, but this is a homework assignment, it's not going to be part of the spaceX programs any time soon.

Comment: So here is hoping the teacher is running a randomly compliant version of a compiler when he checks what gets handed in :-)

Comment: @Galik, it seems that both `clang` and `gcc` have these functions in `iostream` since version 6.0.0 and 6.1 respectively, so a note in the report would clear things up :p

Comment: I admire your tenacity in the face of adversity, but it still gets a down vote. Soz.

Comment: If that's the case  one can simply declare `srand` and `rand` and let the linker do its job.

Comment: Actually this was the case, every available resource I looked at states that rand() had couldn't not be used with these headers, an after a few tests it worked perfectly for my purpose, thank you.

Comment: @SimranBrar, if that's the case you can [accept and upvote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/684852) the answer, it's SO's way of saying thanks.

Comment: @SimranBrar you got lucky, that's all. The code may or may not compile on another compiler. If something isn't legal and you do it anyway and succeed, that doesn't mean you'll continue to succeed later on. You should `#include <random>` for best portability.

Comment: @Galik, you see, sometimes people just want something that works for them, but what I'd like to say in response to you kind compliment is: "We will never surrender..."  

Comment: *"sometimes people just want something that works for them"* - Yet the worst kind of bug is the bug you can´t see that is just waiting to happen because you mistakenly thought you had a working solution. It really doesn´t matter if someone *thinks* a solution "works for them". ***Still a down-vote.*** Soz, not soz. :P

Comment: @Galik I would expect nothing less.